# Losing objects between activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Im passing Serializable objects between activities, but seems that somehow im loosing some of them. Here is what I do:

I parse the objects from json and all is good when I check them. After parsing I pass them to another activity by doing this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Main.class);
 intent.putExtra(Constants.MAIN_ARR_OBJ, mainObjs);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

Now in my second activity I put them in a list, and onItemClick I want to send the object  coresponding to the position clicked to another activity by doing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
Log.v("--", mainObjects.get(position).getAddi_info().getTasks()
.size() + " TASKS SIZE IN MAIN toward second ");
intent.putExtra(Constants.ADDI_INFO_OBJ,
mainObjects.get(position).getAddi_info());
startActivity(intent);
```

And as you see I do a check using `Log.v...` but that gives me size of 0 - that means there is no objects in the arrayList.
In the second activity I get extras by doing

```
mainObjects = (ArrayList<MainScreenObject>) getIntent()
.getSerializableExtra(Constants.MAIN_ARR_OBJ);
```

**EDIT:** In the second activity I get the main object, but that object holds an arrayList of objects, those objects are missing.

Anyone got a clue what can the problem be?

Comment: Don't use serializable, use Parcelable instead. [Here's why](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)

Comment: Make sure your MainScreenObject class is correctly Serializable, like all its base classes are serializable, no transient variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("login", jObj.getString(KEY_LOGIN));
                            intent.putExtra("mdp", jObj.getString(KEY_MDP));
                            intent.putExtra("prenom", jObj.getString(KEY_PRENOM));
                            intent.putExtra("nom", jObj.getString(KEY_NOM));
                            intent.putExtra("mail", jObj.getString(KEY_MAIL));
                            intent.putExtra("tel", jObj.getString(KEY_TEL));
                            startActivity(intent);
```

In your second activity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

          if (intent != null) {
              login = intent.getStringExtra("login");
              mdp = intent.getStringExtra("mdp");

              items.add(intent.getStringExtra("login"));
              items.add(intent.getStringExtra("prenom"));
              items.add(intent.getStringExtra("nom"));
              items.add(intent.getStringExtra("mail"));
              items.add(intent.getStringExtra("tel"));
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I've was reseting the second object arraylist when I was reading the json in a for cycle